# Firebase Functions logs working, but Flutter returns null

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to display Firestore data in a Flutter app. To do that, I created a Firebase function like the following:

```
exports.getHouses = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    let pathBeginning = "users/";
    console.log(data.userID);
    let path = pathBeginning.concat(data.userID, "/houses");
    let houses = [];
    admin.firestore().collection(path).get().then(snapshot => {
    console.log("COLECTION WHERE DOCUMENTS ARE RETREIVED:");
    console.log(path);
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let newHouse = {
                "id": doc.id,
                "address": doc.data().address
            }
            houses = houses.concat(newHouse);
        });
        console.log("THE FOLLOWING LOG SHOULD RETURN THE FULL LIST OF HOUSES:")
        console.log(houses);
        return houses;
    }).catch(reason => {
        response.send(reason);
    });
});
```

I think this part works properly, because logs in Firebase look exactly as expected:

[Firebase logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iFHq.png)

The problem happens when I try to print this data in my Flutter app. To do so, I use the following code:

```
Future<void> listHouses() async {
    var parameters = {
        "userID": "1"
    };
    HttpsCallable getHouses = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("getHouses");
    await getHouses.call(parameters).then((HttpsCallableResult response) {
        print(response.data);
    });
}
```

When called the funtion, it always returns null, even when Firebase log displays everything properly.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me solving this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return` in front of your `get()` call. Without that, the Cloud Functions container doesn't know about the asynchronous `get()` operation and thus will/may terminate the function before loading the data completes.

To fix this, add `return`:

```
return admin.firestore().collection(path).get().then(snapshot => {
  ...
```

This is an extremely common problem within Cloud Functions and when dealing with asynchronous APIs in general, so I recommend taking a moment to read the Firebase documentation on [terminating functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) and watching the video series linked in there.